# The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge - meaning?

Tags: git

I've looked at other questions similar to this but could anyone explain what is going on in this case?

So I have a development server running master, and I created a branch from master called Feature_123.

I have a local copy of master which I have ensured is up to date, with git pull origin master, and then created a LOCAL branch feature_123, and committed my changes and pushed them up to origin feature_123.

I then did a fetch on my development branch, and attempted to merge Feature_123 with feature_123, and get the following message:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten
>   by merge:
>       test_files/lists/file_list

It's a file that another dev is working on, but I'm confused since that file is in my local repo after the latest git pull.

So, why is the file untracked on my server if it's in my local repo? What's going on here?

Comment: `test_files/lists/file_list` is not in git. I don't think anyone else is working on it.

Comment: Is the file source controlled (was it ever committed), or is it just "there", sitting in your working directory?

Comment: This is some file which is tracked in one branch, but not in the other (yet is still present there as an untracked file).  Git is just telling you that this local file would be overwritten by the merge.  As to _why_ you have this situation, you're in the best position to answer that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Git, *untracked* literally means *not in the index* (but, necessarily, in the work-tree, otherwise there's just no file at all).  So `test_files/lists/file_list` is a file that is in your work-tree, but not in your index.

Remember, the index—also called the *staging-area* or sometimes the *cache*—holds a copy of *every* file from this commit, ready to put into the *next* commit.  You can overwrite the version of the file stored in the index using `git add`: this copies whatever you have updated in your work-tree, into your index.  But you can have files in your work-tree that are *not* in your index right now.  Those are your untracked files.

(If those files are ignored as well as untracked, `git status` won't complain about them.  Otherwise, it will.  Note that you cannot ignore a tracked file: only untracked files can be ignored.)

Checking out a commit, to make it the current commit, *fills in* your index from that commit, and simultaneously fills in your work-tree.  This way your current commit, your index, and your work-tree all match.  This is why you must `git add` files after editing them: you have to copy the new version back into the index, overwriting what was there before.  The `git commit` command builds its new commit from whatever is in the index at that time, so you must update any files that you want to be different.

To put it another way, whatever is in the index right now, that's your *proposed next commit*.  It starts out matching your current commit—has all the files with the same contents—and then you modify it using `git add`, to propose for the next commit all the files that *aren't* changed, along with all the ones that *are*.

Note, however, that just because some file isn't in your index right now, does not mean it is not in some commit!  You can *remove* a file from both the index and the work-tree (`git rm somefile`), and now it's in the current commit but not in the index and not in the work-tree—it won't be in the *next* commit you make.

Obviously, it's also possible for you to create a file in your work-tree without adding it to your index (and hence without committing it, even if you make new commits).  That file is untracked, because it is not in your index.  Meanwhile, however, someone *else* could make new commits that *do* have that file.  When you obtain those commits from the other person and then run `git merge`, your Git will tell you: *Hey, this file that you have, untracked, in your work-tree ... I'll have to **overwrite** it with the one in that other guy's commit!  Please get it out of the way first, or commit it, or something, so that I don't overwrite your untracked file!*

This is what you are seeing now.

Answer (score 0):

Why you see the message is explained in the answer by torek.
This set of commands helped me to overcome same situation:

1. git add *
2. git stash
3. git pull

Basically these commands allows you to start tracking untracked files, then all tracked files are stashed away to clean the path for the pull to do its magic and then, well, actual pull command will bring all necessary changes to your local branch. Created stash could be deleted if you have little or no interest in the changes it holds.